# Where is Html property defined in asp.net core razor pages or mvc

Tags: asp.net-core, razor-pages

We can use @Html to generate html directly in razor markup files. But I can't where this Html property is defined. Could anyone help me? Appreciate help in advance.

Comment: What does `But I can't where this Html property is defined.` mean?If you mean you want to know where Html method is defined.It is defined in IHtmlHelper<TModel>.You can refer to  the [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.mvc.rendering.ihtmlhelper-1?view=aspnetcore-5.0).

Comment: no, what I mean Html, I find this is a property Html {get; private set;}. But I can't find where this property is defined. Thanks